# Automatically create site in multisite Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

I have a multisite Wordpress installation that I want to connect to a different application via webservices. I'm getting a list of users and I need to create sites automatically. I'm not sure how exactly to do that. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is handled internally by WordPress using a file called [`/wp-admin/network/site-new.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/network/site-new.php#L82) by calling the [`wpmu_create_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_blog) function.

```
global $wpdb;

$domain = 'example.com';          // your domain (or subdomain)
$path = '/blog';                  // path to your site
$title = 'My Site';               // site title
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); // the user id that owns this site

// hide db errors
$wpdb->hide_errors();
// create the new site
$id = wpmu_create_blog( $domain, $path, $title, $user_id , array( 'public' => true ) );
// enable db errors
$wpdb->show_errors();
```

Comment: So from what I understand, I can create a user first and then call wpmu_create_blog() to create the site for that user.

Comment: Yes, or even use the `user_register` hook to run the code right after a user is added. It takes the `$user_id` as an argument: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register